# How to mock-up the .load function in Qunit?

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, qunit

I have a javascript function I want to test, containing .load. The function looks like this :

```
function getPane(divId) {
    $("#" + divId).load(
                    "Pane.html",
                    function () {
                        //do some work here
                        });
                    });
}
```

I want to test this using Qunit but I'm not sure how to mock this behaviour.

I also do not know how to mock a function that has both .load and .get -

```
 function getPane(divId) {
    $("#" + divId).load("Pane.html", function () {
            $.get("/Config/Pane", function (data) {
                //do work here
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

I'm using only QUnit, no Mockjax or Sinon.js or anything ( I know,I know I should).
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Mocking `load()` isn't too bad, but mocking `$.get()` (in any serious capacity) is harder, unless you don't care about any case but the perfect one... Why not add Mockjax?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I think I'll go with mockjax.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP suggested they might go with Mockjax, I figured I'd add that solution. Note that I'm adding the mocks in a setup method and tearing them down after. This allows for each test to be idempotent. Additionally, your `getPane()` function needs a callback so you can add assertions in your tests.

```
function getPane(divId, cb) {
    $("#" + divId).load("Pane.html", function () {
        $.get("/Config/Pane", function (data) {
            // do work here

            cb(); // callback executed for any additional actions (like tests)
                  // you may want to add some error handling with callback as well
        });
    });
}
```

Then in your `#qunit-fixture` of the qunit test file add the div to put stuff into:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
        <div id="qunit"></div>
        <div id="qunit-fixture">
            <div id="foobar"></div> <!-- our test element -->
        </div>
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Now write your mocks and tests:

```
QUnit.module("some tests", {
    setup: function() {
        $.mockjax({
            url: "Pane.html",
            responseText: "<div>Some HTML content</div>"
        });
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $.mockjax.clear(); // new in 1.6
    }
});

QUnit.asyncTest("test it out", function(assert) {
    getPane("foobar", function() {
        assert.equal($("#foobar div").length, 0, "A new div was added to the page!");
        QUnit.start();
    });
});
```